# How to create a SQL query that calculate monthly grow in population

Tags: mysql

I want to create a SQL query that count the number of babies born in month A, then it should count the babies born in month B but the second record should have the sum of month A plus B. For example;

```
    Month  |  Number
   --------|---------
     Jan   |    5
     Feb   |    7    <- Here were 2 babies born but it have the 5 of the previous month added
     Mar   |    13   <- Here were 6 babies born but it have the 7 of the two previous months added
```

Can somebody maybe please help me with this, is it possible to do something like this?

I have a straight forward table with babyID, BirthDate, etc.

Thank you very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider using a subquery that calculates a running count. Both inner and outer query would be aggregate group by queries:

Using the following sample data:

```
babyID  Birthdate
1       2015-01-01
2       2015-01-15
3       2015-01-20
4       2015-02-01
5       2015-02-03
6       2015-02-21
7       2015-03-11
8       2015-03-21
9       2015-03-27
10      2015-03-30
11      2015-03-31
```

**SQL Query**

```
SELECT MonthName(BirthDate) As BirthMonth, Count(*) As BabyCount,

      (SELECT Count(*) FROM BabyTable t2
      WHERE Month(t2.BirthDate) <= Month(BabyTable.BirthDate)) As RunningCount

FROM BabyTable
GROUP BY Month(BirthDate)
```

**Output**

```
BirthMonth  BabyCount   RunningCount
January            3              3
February           3              6
March              5              11
```